# Creating demo UI ontop of Solr

Tags: lucene, solr, blacklight

I'm looking into some example UI on top of Solr that show of the functionality available in a demo, like e.g. drill down faceted search. I found [Blacklight](http://blacklight.rubyforge.org/), which looks intensively interesting. Is there any other software that is worth researching or is Blacklight definitive the way to go? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at using the Velocity templating built into Solr?   You can find more about "Solritas" here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solritas

I am about to put together a demo Solr site for a presentation, and am going down the Solritas route.  You get faceting, clustering, and more!   And no extra server to run.

Comment: Interesting! I will look into that.